# Why do screenshots appear black when playing games

Tags: windows, powershell, gaming, screenshot

I was just curious to know why normal print screen methods (PowerShell methods, PrintScrn button etc.) just show up black screen when playing fullscreen video games, couldn't find anything to answer that.

I mean like technically, why does it happen, not how to solve it.

P.S
I wasn't quite sure if this is the right StackExchange site to use, so I'm sorry in advance

Comment: I think its because the window managers control over the screen draw is being overridden by the game's drawing mechanism, but that's just a guess, based on things I've seen over the years with old games that drew at specific resolutions without windows.

Comment: Games access the hardware in a fast way and Window's lets them. Another cause but not for games, a program can mark itself to not participate in screenshots. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity

Comment: Also see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas _in plan English?_